# Determine the meaning of a gradient of a graph

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, calculus

How do you determine the gradient of a graph in physics, such as how with a velocity-time graph, the gradient is acceleration.

I want to know the general method for figuring out what the differential of a graph means.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the specific situation.  The general meaning of *gradient* is the spatial rate of change in a quantity.  For example in a temperature field $T(x,y)$, the gradient $\vec {\nabla T}$ tells you the direction of greatest change in the temperature, which physics says will be the direction of greatest heat flow.

In addition, your example of acceleration is *not* a gradient in typical usage of the word. Acceleration is the time derivative of velocity
$$a = \frac {dv}{dt} $$

A time derivative is usually referred to as a *rate*.  A spatial derivative is referred to as a gradient.